# row click event in dynamic created table return undefined error?

Tags: javascript

I use below code to create a table and add row click event which returned the value of first td in it.

```
function bclick(){
    var result=[];
    SAPget.step4QueryTable(function(data){
    var tbody=document.querySelector("tbody");
         for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)  
            {
                var tr=document.createElement("tr");
                tbody.appendChild(tr);
                var td=document.createElement("td");  
                tr.appendChild(td);
                td.innerHTML=data[i].code; 
                var td1=document.createElement("td");
                tr.appendChild(td1);                
                if (data[i].name!="")
                    { 
                        td1.innerHTML=data[i].name; 
                    }
                else
                    { 
                        td1.innerHTML="";    
                    }
                tr.onclick=function fun(){

                    alert(this.children("td:first"));
                    }  

            }

        }
    )
}
```

But it always alert undefined. I debug it in IE and the children has length 2 but value is empty.Can someone tell me what's wrong?  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

If I want to get first child of `tr` element

I would do

```
alert(this.firstElementChild.textContent);
```

What I know is

`children` returns HTMLCollection

so insted of using `children` use `firstElementChild.textContent`

Also if you want to get text of any other child you can use

```
this.children[1].textContent // As 0 will be first td, 1 will be second td
```